# Why am i getting this error: "Type 'React.ReactNode' is not assignable to type" in jenkins?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jenkins

I'm having a problem building my react app in jenkins.

[image]

There is no problem when building on local, but there is a problem in Jenkins.
What should I do?

Comment: try to delete `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` on local and see if you still have a complete build

Comment: @CyberDracula I try the process on local: `rm -rf node_modules` -> `rm -rf package-lock.json`-> `npm install`-> build. and the process was successful

Comment: you could also check if the `npm` major version used by Jenkins is the same as yours.

Comment: Looks like you have wrong import somewhere